# Don't show votes for posts when reviewing

Tags: feature-request, review, voting

When you review first posts or late answers, the votes for this question/answer are displayed (maybe this is true for the other review queue as well, but I don't have enough rep to check yet).

I try not to look at this vote count, because I don't want to be influenced by the other reviewers, but ignoring a big "-5" is nearly impossible so I already believe that the question/answer is bad before I even start reading it.

I would suggest to hide the vote count during the review process in order to make the reviews more neutral.

Answer (score 3):

Vote hiding has been discussed for various situations before, [here's the first example I turned up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68815/how-about-hiding-answer-score-for-first-few-hours), and has yet to gain any traction.

The consensus is generally that everyone should be strong-willed enough to overcome any biases that others' votes might induce and not showing votes is overly mollycoddling.